# Merge or synonymize Cold Fusion tags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, synonym-request, retag-request

[cfml](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cfml) and [coldfusion-10](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion-10) should be merged with [coldfusion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion).

[coldfusion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion) is the most popular tag of them all, but they are all the same thing and there aren't very many questions associated with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they were all created by the same user, too.  SO's tag wikis seem to suggest that [coldfusion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion) and [cfml](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cfml) are *not* quite similar.  If they are, then someone else can change them.  <s>For now, I've retagged the [coldfusion-10](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion-10) question with [coldfusion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion), and the former will die soon.</s>

**UPDATE:** That question has been retagged by the OP with [this reason](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/32971/5).

Comment: they are different.  Cold Fusion is a platform and CFML is a language that is used by other platforms as well as ColdFusion

Comment: @Malachi: Thought so.  In that case, no further action is needed.

Comment: I am editing the tag wiki for Coldfusion, the wiki said it was a language better known as CFML

Comment: I've proposed more tag wiki changes for [tag:coldfusion] and [tag:cfml] to clarify their relationship.

Comment: @200_success thank you, I stole most of my information from wikipedia. I haven't used Coldfusion or CFML myself so I knew very little.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [coldfusion-10](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion-10) and [coldfustion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfustion) are being used and there is a difference in the coding style and/or syntax, techniques, methods.

[cfml](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cfml) is about CFML Language which can be used in several different environments and not just ColdFusion